# Block web traffic from internet (public access)

Tags: jelastic

I just configured an NGINX instance on the Jelastic platform.
In my environment's firewall inbound rules there are now a few default rules added.
With source All. (HTTP, HTTPS, ...)
I changed the source of these firewall rules to Local LAN.
So I expect that when I go to my Jelastic public URL in my browser on my own computer, I do not get a website but I'm blocked by the firewall.

This is not happening. I do not want the website to be used from the outside. This environment will host some REST API's and workers running on the inside and only triggered by other environments I have.

Kind regards.
Roel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recommend following this guide to disable access to your container (CT) from the outside: https://docs.jelastic.com/release-notes-59/#restrict-node-access-via-shared-load-balancer-slb

However, please keep in mind that you'll not be able to access this CT from another CT too.

**UPDATE:**
little clarification

If "Access via SLB" disabled, the nodes within the layer are inaccessible via SLB (including the Open in Browser button in the dashboard) and return the 403 "Forbidden error" instead of the intended service. Herewith, access via the private network from the other nodes of the environment, access via SSH and access via endpoints from the public network is not affected.
We also want to draw your attention to that described feature is available from the Jelastic PaaS 5.9 release